# ¿Cómo hacer un left_join teniendo en cuenta 2 columnas?

Tags: r, join

Tengo un df con 3 columnas y necesito traer datos de otro df, pero necesito que coincidan con los datos de 2 columnas, la columna "PROVINCIA" y la columna "AÑO".

Intenté utilizar este código pero no funcionó

```
left_join(poblacion, by ="PROVINCIA", "ANIO")
```

Comment: `left_join(poblacion, by = c("PROVINCIA", "ANIO"))`